# Drawing arrows with two different colors depending on the direction in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like to change the color of arrows depending on the direction. I figured out to insert the arrows in the plot, but at the moment they are all black. I would like to have arrows from left to right in green and arrows from right to left in red. Is that possible?

Here is my "short" code:

```
library(ggplot2)

name = c("Name1","Name2", "Name1", "Name2")
time = c("1", "3","4","2")
value = c(5.1, 4.8, 4.1, 6.3)
data <- data.frame(name, time, value) 

p <- ggplot(data, aes(x=value, y=name)) +
  geom_point(aes(colour=time), shape=16, size=6) +
  geom_path(aes(group=name), arrow=arrow(length=unit(0.15,"cm")), colour="black", size=1) 
print(p)
```

Thank you in advance for any help you can provide!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like `n` can be used as a proxy for the arrow direction, so:

```
p +  geom_path(aes(group=n), arrow=arrow(length=unit(0.15,"cm")), colour=c("red","green")[factor(n)], size=1)
```

However, more generally I suppose you would want something like:

```
p +  geom_path(aes(group=n), arrow=arrow(length=unit(0.15,"cm")), colour=c("red","black","green")[(sign(tapply(v,n,diff))+2)[n]], size=1)
```

Is `v` meant to be used as a factor rather than a numeric value?

Comment: Thank you! If I understand the code correctly I have to map every n to a color. I thought there is a possibility to use information about the arrow direction? Because the length of my dataset is variable.

Comment: The mapping uses the information in the data to determine the direction, but more so in the second example.

Comment: v is an numeric value. I fixed the example. Thank you for your second example. I get an error "Error: Incompatible lengths for set aesthetics: colour, size". I think I know whats the idea with the 'tapply' is, but I'm not able to figure out why the error appears.

Comment: Great! Thx a lot. I needed some time to recognize that I need **n** and **v** as values to get it work with my live data.

Answer (score 1):

You can add new column to the data which I named as `direction`. It is calculated for each level of `name` using function `ddply` from library `plyr`. `direction` variable can have two values `TRUE` or `FALSE` depending on difference between first and second `value` value for particular `name` level (positive or negative).

```
library(plyr)
data<-ddply(data,.(name),transform,direction=((value[1]-value[2])>0))
data
   name time value direction
1 Name1    1   5.1      TRUE
2 Name1    4   4.1      TRUE
3 Name2    3   4.8     FALSE
4 Name2    2   6.3     FALSE
```

The use this new variable to set color for `geom_path()`.

```
ggplot(data, aes(x=value, y=name)) +
  geom_point(aes(colour=time), shape=16, size=6) +
  geom_path(aes(group=name), arrow=arrow(length=unit(0.15,"cm")), size=1,color=c("red","blue")[factor(data$direction)])
```

Comment: Thank you for your code! I also had an extra column with the information in my mind. But thought that there has to be a way to use the information already in the plot. The solution to use ddply here is a good idea. Thanks!